# Need to calculate columns from CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`incidentcountlevel1` and `examcount` were two column names on CSV file. I want to calculate two columns based on these. I have written the script below but it's failing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time, os, fnmatch, shutil
df = pd.read_csv(r"/home/corp_sourcing/Metric_Fact_20180324_1227.csv",header='infer',skiprows=[1])
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"/home/corp_sourcing/Metric_Fact_20180324_1227.csv",header='infer',skiprows=[1])
df3 = pd.read_csv("/home/corp_sourcing/Metric_Fact_20180324_1227.csv",header='infer',converters={"incidentcountlevel1":int})
inc_count_lvl_1 = df3.loc[:, ['incidentcountlevel1']]
exam_count=df3.loc[:, ['examcount']]

for exam_count in exam_count: #need to iterate this col to calculate for each row

if exam_count < 1:
        print "IPTE Cannot be calculated"

else:
        if inc_count_lvl_1 > 5:
        ipte1= (inc_count_lvl_1/exam_count)*1000
    else:

        dof = 2*(inc_count_lvl_1+ 1)
        chi_square=chi2.ppf(0.5,dof)
        ipte1=(chi_square/(2*exam_count))×1000
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Read [how to ask pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). getting this error while 
using 
if exam_count < 1:

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `lamda function` on pandas column.
Just created an example using numpy. You can change according to your case

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30], "B": [20, 30, 50]})
>>> df['new_column'] = np.multiply(df['A'], df['B'])
>>> df
    A   B  new_column
0  10  20         200
1  20  30         600
2  30  10         1500
```

or you can create your own function:

```
>>> def fx(x, y):
...     return x*y
...
>>> df['new_column'] = np.vectorize(fx)(df['A'], df['B'])
>>> df
    A   B  new_column
0  10  20         200
1  20  30         600
2  30  10         1500
```

I your case, the solution might look like this.

```
df['new_column'] = np.vectorize(fx)(df['examcount'], df['incidentcountlevel1'])

def fx(exam_count,inc_count_lvl_1):
    if exam_count < 1:
        return -1 ##whatever you want
    else:
            if inc_count_lvl_1 > 5:
            ipte1= (inc_count_lvl_1/exam_count)*1000
        else:

            dof = 2*(inc_count_lvl_1+ 1)
            chi_square=chi2.ppf(0.5,dof)
            ipte1=(chi_square/(2*exam_count))×1000 

        return ipte1
```

If you dont want to use `lamda fucntions` then you can use `iterrows`.
[iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) is a generator which yield both index and row.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row['examcount'], row['incidentcountlevel1']
    #do your stuff.
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Need to know, how to read the column value from csv file and use those in for and if loop to compare it with a integer value and then calculate with some arithmetic operation as mentioned in my program.
Sorry, i'm new to python any help is appreciated , if related to my program which is shared

Comment: such as 'incidentcountlevel1' and 'examcount' needs to be read from csv file and if the value matches with a numeric value then proceed with calculated columns and also want to place a for loop  on 'examcount' to iterate all the rows one by one

Comment: incidentcountlevel1  examcount
2   0
21   0
33   1
4   2
11   3
6   4

Comment: Just added more information to the solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(r"/home/corp_sourcing/Metric_Fact_20180324_1227.csv",header='infer')
inc_count_lvl_1 = df.loc[:, ['incidentcountlevel1']]
exam_count=df.loc[:, ['examcount']]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if exam_count < 1:
                print "Exam < 1"
        else:
                if inc_count_lvl_1 > 5:
                        ipte1= (inc_count_lvl_1/exam_count)*1000
                else:
                        dof = 2*(inc_count_lvl_1+ 1)
                        chi_square=chi2.ppf(0.5,dof)
                        ipte1 = (chi_square /( 2 * exam_count))*1000

Comment: if exam_count < 1:
  File "/home/corp_sourcing/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
getting error this error

Comment: The code looks messy in the comments. Can you please add sample input data and expected output. It would be easier to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: incidentcountlevel1  examcount  ipte1 ipte2
2                          0
21                          0
33                          1
4                          2
11                          3
6                          4

Comment: My browser is bit old, the comments are bit messy, can you help me with the code which i shared and error, basically i am reading a csv file for column values, there are numeric values in it and IPTE1 and IPTE2 column were blank and calculated values needs to be put there.